# tcp client with socket.io (nodejs)

Tags: c#, node.js, tcp, connection, socket.io

I need a nodejs server connected to a C# application, i don't like using third-party libraries, so I've been trying using a `TcpClient`, the server is something like this:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8000);
io.socket.on('connection',function(socket)
{
 console.log("connected");
}
```

and on the C# project:

```
var client = new TcpClient(Server,8000);
Socket s = client.Client;
if (!s.Connected)
{
   s.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket,
   SocketOptionName.ReceiveBuffer, 16384);
   MessageBox.Show("disconnected");
}
else
{
   MessageBox.Show("connected");
   s.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("something"));
}
```

for what i understood on the `"something"` i should write something that would trigger the "on('connection')" on the nodejs side, am i missing something?

PS: if you know a good third-party library for what i need you could mention it

Comment: <strike>don't like using third-party libraries</strike> enjoy reinventing the wheel. There, FTFY ;)

Comment: true :P, but i like to try to make cleaner as possible, if  for example, my problem is just: "connection: {data: value}", and it works fine, i don't need third party libraries... but if i need to write a book, i would think about third-party libraries ;). i like to know how it could work before using third-party stuff.

Comment: Isn't node.js an HTTP-based protocol? Or does it support socket-level programming? If it's HTTP only, you'll have to sent HTTP requests rather than just writing data to the socket.

Comment: node.js supports socket-level programming

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the server on('connection') should fire at the time you construct your TcpClient object because that's when the connection occurs, rather than at the point where you attempt to send some data.

Comment: the `MessageBox.Show("connected");` is firing when the socket.io server is running, but the `on('connetion')` is not